# Notice and warning when using OOP php

Tags: php, oop

```
         <!----  Database File  --->
      <?php
      require_once 'config.php';

      class MySQLDatabase {

          private $connection;

          function __construct() {
              $this->open_connection();
          }

          public function open_connection() {
              $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
              if(!$this->connection) {
                  die("Database connection Failed: " .mysqli_error($this->connection));
              }else {
                  $db_select = mysqli_select_db($this->connection, DB_NAME);
                  if(!$db_select) {
                     die("Database connection Failed: " .mysqli_error($this->connection)); 
                  }
              }
          }

          public function close_connection() {
              if(isset($this->connection)) {
                  mysqli_close($this->connection);
                  unset($this->connection);
              }
          }

          public function query($sql) {
              $result = mysqli_query($sql, $this->connection);
              $this->confirm_query($result);
              return $result;

          }


          private function confirm_query($result) {
              if(!$result) {
                   die("Database connection Failed: " .mysqli_error($this->connection)); 
              }
          }


      }

      $database = new MySQLDatabase();
      $database->close_connection();

      ?>

      <!----Config FIle which ---->

      <?php
          defined('DB_SERVER') ? null : define("DB_SERVER","localhost");
          defined('DB_USER')   ? null : define("DB_USER", "faizy");
          defined('DB_PASS')   ? null : define("DB_PASS", "faizy");
          defined('DB_NAME')   ? null : define("DB_NAME", "photo_gallery");
      ?>

      <!---index.php---->

      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">

      <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <title>Document</title>
      </head>

      <body>
          <?php
          require_once '../includes/database.php';
          if(isset($database)){ echo "true"; } else { echo "false"; }
          echo "<h1>Working</h1>";
          ?>
      </body>

      </html>
```

Below are the warning and notice shown by my browser can anyone suggest why these are coming,When i use single php and try to connect that it connects,but when i use different function files and used OOP php than always these error are shown,Can anyone please help to solve these warnings and Notice

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_SERVER - assumed 'DB_SERVER' in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\oop\includes\database.php on line 13

Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_USER - assumed 'DB_USER' in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\oop\includes\database.php on line 13

Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_PASS - assumed 'DB_PASS' in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\oop\includes\database.php on line 13

Notice: Use of undefined constant DB_NAME - assumed 'DB_NAME' in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\oop\includes\database.php on line 13

Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\oop\includes\database.php on line 13

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\oop\includes\database.php on line 13

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\oop\includes\database.php on line 15
Database connection Failed:
```

Comment: You will probably need to provide the errors you are receiving in order for anyone to help.

Comment: Now I have edited my question,Can you plz review it again

Comment: Have you verified that `config.php` is in the same folder/directory as `database.php`?

Comment: yes config in the same directory of database,they both are in includes folder

Comment: Possible solution from a comment in the docs - http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php#77204

Comment: The only way I can see you would be receiving the warnings about undefined constants is if the config file is not loading. Does the server have read access to the config file?

Answer (score 1):

I just made a test using all the above code in the three separate files and it all works for me. All I changed was the database name and pass to be one of my databases. You must be linking to the files wrong.

Comment: I have also done the same thing but it is not working,Same warnings and error again,These three files are in different files,These error occus when i use OOP php

Comment: Swap the require config line with the code from config. Then add index (without require) below the closing ?>. Then visit database.php in your browser. It should work presuming your db exists.

Comment: Here is my code that works all in one file: http://pastebin.com/0Y2UGSgg

I changed db details obviously. Using yours i got the last 2 warnings as obviously I don't have a database called photo_gallery

Answer (score 0):

Put your constant definitions above the database logic and it'll work. That'll confirm that your require path is incorrectly configured.

Comment: That is 3 separate files in the code block. The OP just doesn't make it clear with the formatting here.

Comment: I'm aware of that, that's why he needs to stop trying to separate that logic out to confirm the root cause of the problem and abandon using the config file and stick it above his database logic. Then decouple after he knows why it wasn't working.

Comment: I dont know bro why it is not working,I think that this is the main issue (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.)

Comment: It's a step in the right direction if you put your constants in the config file in place of the require for the config. When those errors are eliminated, update your question details with the new error output.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, now its work when i put the constant in the same file of database,But why this was happening

Comment: It may have been something to do with the way you were requiring the config file :) Could be anything. Could be file permissions. The most obvious might be the wrong relative path. `require "config.php"` assumes the file is in the same directory as your database file

Comment: yes jonathan config is in the same directory of database file than why it was happening

Comment: It could be some kind of saving face error. I'm not sure. In any case if this was helpful please up vote. It's a responsibility more than a privilege to do so, ;)